# Probability of getters and setters getting inlined by the compiler

Tags: java, performance, compiler-construction, jit

My question is pretty straightforward:

**Q:** What is the chance that a getter / setter method will get inlined by the compiler in Java?
(Obviously there isn't a definite answer to this, but other information would be appreciated)

**Extra:** I understand there is always a chance the compiler (Standard and JIT) will decide to make a method inline, and when it comes to getters and setters this is usually what the programmer wants.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C1 or C2 (i.e. client or server )? But either way extremely high, so you can assume it as long as the code is 'hot'. If you want to prove it, use -XX:++PrintAssembly to check the generated code. The only issue would be inlining "budget" which is more limited on the C1 compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler (javac) tend to have negligible impact on optimization,
as optimization happens at run time.

As of the JIT yes,it will probably inline either sooner or later.depending on how heavily the code is used, so a function call overhead may be seen at first, but when the getter/setter has been called sufficiently often then it is inlined.

Comment: javac has a hard time inlining because we still want a valid stack trace at any point in time. But then why care about the call overhead of a method that's called only a few hundred times? C2 has a large enough inline budget which in practice means a getter/setter will always be inlined anyhow. C1 could be more limited in that regard though.

Comment: true. I was trying to address the question of probability of them being inlined.

Answer (score 3):

The *compiler* may inline when a method is `final` and the accessed fields are accessible to the caller. Then it's up to the compiler to determine whether the method is "simple" enough for inlining.

In practice, setting or getting a field is generally considered simple enough, so a final accessor for an accessible field will be inlined. Accessors for private fields will be inlined within their declaring class; accessors for protected fields will be inlined throughout the declaring package and any derived classes; &c.

At runtime, the JIT is likely to perform additional inlining based on analysis of running code.

Comment: Does the amount of times that a getter / setter is ued affects the probably that the JIT will consider to inline it? Is there something similar to the `inline` (C++) keyword in Java, which recommends inlining a method?

Comment: Yes, usage is a factor for the JIT at runtime. But there is no explicit inline hint you can give the compiler.

Comment: Thanks. I must've missed it the first time - what did u mean by `final accessor`?

Comment: An accessor that is declared `final` (or is a method of a `final` class). Non-final (essentially "virtual") methods can't be inlined at compile-time, because the actual method to be invoked has to be resolved at runtime. However, there might be cases where the JIT can inline non-final methods. For example, it knows all loaded classes; if no subclasses have been loaded, it safely assume that a superclass' version of a method is the only one possible and inline it.

Comment: I am aware of the use of the final methods, my question was rigged towards their use with accessors. Just to to be sure - does making accessor methods `final` increase their chance of being inlined? Does JIT care about this or only the JavaC compiler?

Comment: Yes, `final` accessors have a better chance of being inlined. It depends on the JIT compiler, but some use the `final` declaration a hint for more aggressive inlining.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine about zero (at least in the non-JIT case), since these are Java Bean conventions and they always need to be public, so the compiler cannot predict who might call the methods. You might change the implementation of one of these which would break an inlined caller. There is nothing to require that they need to be implemented only to set a field.