# Java, declaring final methods inside a final class

Tags: java

For documentation purpose, is it ideal/good practice to declare methods as final inside final class?

Comment: opinion-based, sorry

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766476/non-final-methods-in-a-final-class

Comment: What does `final` have to do with documentation purposes?  Keywords are not a substitute for documentation.  Javadoc is documentation.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add boilerplate `final`, because all methods in a final class are implicitly final anyway. So to your point it's not a good practice.